# Warning: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning

Tags: boot, 17.10

I have been running Ubuntu 17 for a few months now, yesterday my network manager seems to have failed so I figured I would reboot and see if that solved it.

When I boot I get the error in the title.

Been reading a bunch of other posts, have tried to set lvmetad to 0 in some file. I can access virtual terminal and all files, but cannot update the system as I can't access Internet.

Found out that my apparmor has not started, guessing that is why I can't access Internet?

If anyone have a solution, preferably without reinstalling Ubuntu. I have some things that I would need to push to got before I can reinstall, so if i can have some help getting internet connections that would be fine.